# Why is this cshtml giving run time error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Can anybody tell me why is this code giving runtime error:

```
  @if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {


        Welcome <b>Page.User.Identity.Name;</b>!
        [ Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account"); ]
       <br />     
        <br />     
        [ Html.ActionLink("Change Password", "ChangePassword", "Account"); ]
         <br />  
    }
    else { 
        [Html.ActionLink("Candidate Login", "LogOn", "Account",new { id = 1 },null);]
    <br />     
    <br />     
        [Html.ActionLink("Employer Login", "LogOn", "Account", new { id = 2 }, null);]
    <br />     

}
```

What should I do to avoid it? I am getting crazy behind these braces and html mixed up

Comment: What are these [] brackets you are using? Have you tried `@Html.ActionLink...` instead?

Comment: And what error message are you getting?

Comment: @Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen: Those brackets are just for formatting. Nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give it a shot:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
  Welcome <b>@Page.User.Identity.Name</b>!
  @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account")
  <br />     
  <br />     
  @Html.ActionLink("Change Password", "ChangePassword", "Account")
   <br />  
 }
 else
 { 
   @Html.ActionLink("Candidate Login", "LogOn", "Account",new { id = 1 },null)
   <br />     
   <br />     
   @Html.ActionLink("Employer Login", "LogOn", "Account", new { id = 2 }, null)
   <br />     
 }
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. This line is giving error "Welcome <b>@Page.User.Identity.Name;</b>!" If I remove it it works fine.

Comment: Resolved it by using this "    <span>Welcome <b>@Page.User.Identity.Name;</b>!</span>". God it wasted 1 complete hour.

Comment: Better to waste one hour to get it to work, than to waste one hour and it still isn't working ;)